# AlarmManager with notification not firing

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm making an app with a persistent notification, so I'm trying to use `AlarmManager` to periodically update the notification.

I've extended `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class Notification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateNotification();
    }
```

If I just run notification.onReceive, the notification updates as expected, so I believe the problem isn't here. I've also added code in 'MainActivity.onCreate`that is supposed to create and run an`alarmManager`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000,
        pendingIntent);
}
```

Nothing appears to happen when I run the app, but I see the `AlarmManager` service draining my battery, so I'm pretty sure something is running. I think the problem is with `pendingIntent`; Either that or I am missing something (haven't done anything else in the project relating to `AlarmManager`).

Coding this on Android Studio and running it on my Note 4. `minSdkVersion 19`, `targetSdkVersion 21`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try logging something in the `onReceive`. If you see it, then the problem is not with `AlarmManager`.

Comment: I just tried that, the message does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out the example I was looking at didn't mention that I had to add

```
<receiver android:name=".Notification" />
```

to the manifest.